# dictionary<int, guid> how to take value field that is Guid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I was struggling a lot to get a Guid Value from Dictionary. Somebody please help me out.It is showing System.FormatException.Thank you advance.

My code:

```
Dictionary<int, Guid> products = productRepository.QueryNoTracking()
    .Select(x => new { x.ID, x.ProductKey }) 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ProductKey, x => x.ID);
```

From this I need to take productID from Position group Entity:-

```
var positionGroup = new Entities.PositionGroup();

positionGroup.ProductID = (Guid?)products
   .Where(s => s.Key == productKey)
   .Select(s => s.Value).ToString();
```

Comment: You create a dictionary, why not use it? As in `products[productkey]`?

Comment: FWIW, the reason the LINQ isn't working is that `Where` will return a collection of matches, so you're getting the `ToString` of a collection, not a single value.  `FirstOrDefault` is more along the lines of what you'd need, but as the answer shows - use the power of the dictionary instead.

Comment: That I don't know how to implement. Can You please help me!

Comment: Can you pls explain some more in detail as I'm a beginner for .Net echnology? @oerkelens

Comment: One wonders if you're using the `products` dictionary for any other purpose, and whether you could just get the guid direct from the `productRepository` in the first place?  That would satisfy _"I must use the LINQ query, it is the requirement."_.

Comment: Guid productId; positionGroup.ProductID = products.TryGetValue(positionGroup.PositionGroupKey, out productId) == true ? productId : (Guid?)null; ..................................This worked for me guys Thankyou all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a LINQ query to find the key/value in a dictionary:

```
Guid productID;
bool knownProductKey = products.TryGetValue(productKey, out productID);
if(knownProductKey)
    positionGroup.ProductID = productID;
else
    positionGroup.ProductID = new Nullable<Guid>();
```

Comment: I must use the LINQ query, it is the requirement.

Comment: @HelenAnita: the requirement is to use extremely inefficient code?

Comment: Ok..I'm trying @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @HelenAnita: of course the dictionary makes only sense when you create it once and then use it everywhere else for lookups like i did. If you always create it before you use it it's not efficient.

Comment: Guid productId;         positionGroup.ProductID = products.TryGetValue(positionGroup.PositionGroupKey, out productId) == true ? productId : (Guid?)null;

Answer (score 1):

If you want help you really should post enough code that we can just copy-paste it into Visual Studio & fix it easily.

The limited info you've given makes it really time consuming to get a working sample for you.

In any case, this is more or less what the other comments are suggesting.

You will have to get it adjust for your needs because there's not enough info to give you working code.

```
var positionGroup = new Entities.PositionGroup()
{
    ProductID = productRepository.QueryNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.ProductKey==productKey)
        .Select(x => x.ID}) 
}
```